# How can we convert an existing java project with lib folder to Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, dependencies, maven-plugin

I have a old java project that does not use Maven or any other build tool. All the Dependencies/external jars that I need to run my project are located in a "libs" folder in my root directory. Now, i want to completely "mavenize' my project and discard the library folder.

I dont want to find all dependencies from mvn central repository and copy in the pom.xml. I have read some answers which use the `install:install-file` but i dont understand clearly.

Is there any fast way in which i can run my project using maven and get rid of the lib folder completely from my project?

Kindly help as im a newbie in Maven.

[lib folder in java project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOccj.png)

Comment: Based on the image I've seen...the dependencies look like usual one which are available in Central so it shouldn't be that hard to find those dependencies via https://search.maven.org/ and add them to your pom file... and the way to go via install-file is simply wrong... sorry to say but if you don't want to search those deps from central then you are faced that the usual to do such things is to search up the deps fro m central and add them to your pom ... afterwards you are getting rid of the lib folder as intended...

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is what you don't want to do.

You need to look up all the dependencies on MavenCentral and copy the XML to the POM.

Comment: Sure Fabian, will go with the correct way. :)